# Ocaml module и module type

Tags: ocaml

Мы сейчас проходим в универе по OCaml модули и типы модулей. Нам дан модуль:

```
module Comp = struct
  type t = int ref
  let create () = ref 0
  let read s = !s
  let write s =  s:= !s+1
end
```

У нас задача написать два типа модулей, без имплементации. Я написал:

```
module type USER = sig 
  type t
  val read : t -> int
end

module type ADMIN = sig 
  type t 
  val create : unit -> t
  val read : t -> int
  val write : t -> unit
end
```

и потом остается только написать

```
module User : USER = Comp;;
module Admin : ADMIN = Comp;;
```

и это работает. Но как я понял из задания, надо сделать, чтобы тип t у них был общий, чтобы USER мог читать ADMIN.t . Моя идея в том, чтобы написать и в USER, и в ADMIN

```
type t = Comp.t
```

и тогда они делят один тип и все работает, но я боюсь, что это неправильно. Писать, например, в USER что-то вроде

```
type t = ADMIN.t
```

и наоборот нельзя, потому что так можно использовать только модуль, а ADMIN и USER это тип модуля, что то вроде интерфейса.

Вопрос: как лучше и правильней всего объявить, что в USER и в ADMIN один общий тип?

Comment: Можно полюбопытствовать, а в каком университете учат OCaml'у?

Comment: Paris VII Diderot

Comment: ахх, а уж было понадеялся))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как лучше и правильней сильно зависит от контекста. Тип модуля является абстракцией и если ограничить тип `t`, потребовав, что бы он был именно конкретной реализаций `Comp.t`, то это сведет на нет всю абстракцию. Абстракция не должна, в общем случае, ссылать на реализацию. Поэтому конкретизировать нужно уже на уровне реализаций, не абстракций. Для этого нужно использовать type sharing constraint на уровне реализаций, например вот так:

```
 module Admin : ADMIN = Comp
 module User : USER with type t = Admin.t = Comp
```

Так как равенство рефлексивно, то нет никакой разницы кто равен кому.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего имеется в виду, что надо возвращать юзера и админа с конкретным `Comp.t` внутри. Синтаксис примерно такой:

`Asdf: USER with type t = Comp.t ...`